# Efficiently querying a graph structure

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I have a database which consists of a graph. The table I need to access looks like this:

```
Sno    Source    Dest
1       'jack'   'bob'
2       'jack'   'Jill'
3       'bob'    'Jim'
```

Here `Sno` is the primary key. Source and Destination are 2 non-unique numbers which represents an edge between nodes in my graph. My `Source` and `Dest` may also be strings and not necessarily an number data type. I have around 5 million entries in my database and I have built it using Postgresql with Psycopg2 for python.

It is very easy and quick to query for the primary key. However, I need to frequently query this database for all the `dest` a particular source is connected to. Right now I achieve this by calling the query:

```
SELECT * FROM name_table WHERE Source = 'jack'
```

This turns out to be quite inefficient (Up to 2 seconds per query) and there is no way that I can make this the primary key as it is not unique. Is there any way that I can make an index based on these repeated values and query it quickly?

Comment: You have set an index on the `Source` field? As explained here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html

Comment: To set an index you need to make it a primary key right? Doesn't it require a unique key? If not how do I set this index?

Comment: You should read the documentation as I have posted. This tells you *everything* on indexing with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should make your query much faster.

`CREATE INDEX table_name_index_source ON table_name Source;`

However there are many options which you can use

**PostgreSQL Documentation**

```
CREATE [ UNIQUE ] INDEX [ CONCURRENTLY ] [ name ] ON table [ USING method ]
    ( { column | ( expression ) } [ COLLATE collation ] [ opclass ] [ ASC | DESC ] [ NULLS { FIRST | LAST } ] [, ...] )
    [ WITH ( storage_parameter = value [, ... ] ) ]
    [ TABLESPACE tablespace ]
    [ WHERE predicate ]
```

Read more about indexing with PostgreSQL in their [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html).

**Update**

If your table is that *small* as yours, this will for help for sure. However if your dataset is growing you should probably consider a schema change to have unique values which can be indexed more efficiently.